# How to specify path DirectoryDirectory in Gradle on Windows?

Tags: gradle

I have following task in Gradle.
I can run this task on linux, but I am having trouble specifying
directory path on Windows environment.
Could anyone help me how should I write?

```
task copyData(type: Zip) {
    archiveFileName = "compresseddata.zip"
    destinationDirectory = "***HERE***" 
    from configurations.compile
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use forward-slashes - it works for both Windows and Linux.

And just a heads-up: unless you are on a very old version of Gradle, then `configurations.compile` is likely wrong. If you want either compile-time or runtime dependencies, use `configurations.compileClasspath` and `configurations.runtimeClasspath` respectivly (the configuration simply called `compile` is deprecated and does not always hold all dependencies).

Example:

```
task copyData(type: Zip) {
    archiveFileName = "compresseddata.zip"
    destinationDirectory = file("$buildDir/myData") 
    from configurations.runtimeClasspath
}
```